# Edit /etc/passwd file from grub

Tags: shell, login, root, grub, accounts

I tried installing zsh on ubuntu ( 14.04). When I switched to zsh, I was unable to go into super user mode.

If I do a su it asks for passwd and on entering the correct password, it says:

```
Cannot execute which zsh: No such file or directory
```

But when I enter an incorrect password and press enter 4-5 times, it shows nothing.

On checking my `/etc/passwd` file, it showed:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:which zsh
```

I tried to edit the file and save but it shows

```
Unable to save /etc/passwd
```

I have tried to change the runlevel to 1 via grub, but it results in an error:

```
APCI PCC probe failed
```

I am running Ubuntu on VirtualBox.

Comment: Ubuntu grub has option to go into recovery. Also, you can change  an option to boot into bash directly. Can't recall which, though

Comment: even during recovery; setting **root: Drop out to root shell** asks for passwd, which when entered correct gives: *which zsh: No such file or directory*

Answer (score 1):

You should remove from the password file the `which` word...
It should be something like :

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/zsh
```

Where /bin/zsh is the path to the Z shell binary.
In the current config, the login process is trying to execute `which zsh` and that command is failing.

Also, edit the file as root, with `sudo vim /etc/passwd` for example because it is a file which is writable only by root.

If you can't `sudo` or `su`, then boot into recovery mode (choose Advanced option for Ubuntu in GRUB boot loader, then choose Ubuntu...(recovery mode), then choose root/Drop to root shell prompt). After this, remount the `/` filesystem as read-write (`mount -o remount,rw /`) and then you can edit the content of the `/etc/passwd` file. Tested this on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Hi there, I tried editing the file, but as I mentioned above, it shows I cannot edit the file(unless I am the root - and also I am unable to become the root because the su command doesn't work): **Unable to save /etc/passwd**

Comment: Filesystem is mounted read only. Try remount as read write

Comment: I tried going to /etc and doing **mount -o remount rw** and got **mount: only root can do that**

Comment: boot into recovery mode (choose Advanced option for Ubuntu in GRUB boot loader, then choose Ubuntu...(recovery mode), then choose root/Drop to root shell prompt). After this, remount the `/` filesystem as read-write (`mount -o remount,rw /`) and then you can edit the content of the `/etc/passwd`. Tested this on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I booted into the recovery mode and chose: root: Drop out to root shell prompt, it again gives: Give the root password for maintainence or press Ctrl+D to continue, on giving the right password, it shows which zsh: No such file or Directory

Comment: in this case you should try booting an Ubuntu install disk and drop to shell (or use the Try Ubuntu option) and then try to mount the drive and change the file

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit files from the Grub prompt (Grub can only read files, it doesn't have any write support). You need to boot Linux¹.

If you can't log in normally, you can completely bypass the normal boot process and start just a kernel and a shell. At the Grub prompt, press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the boot sequence, add `init=/bin/bash` to the end of the `linux=…` line, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot. You'll get a root shell and nothing else. Run

```
mount -t proc proc /proc
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Now run `chsh -s /bin/zsh root` to repair your user database.

Next, reboot with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, or boot normally with

```
mount -o remount,ro /
umount /proc
exec /sbin/init
```

Tip: run `chsh` without a *user* argument. That way, it validates the shell.

Tip: when you're changing some configuration, always keep a shell open and test the configuration. If you made a mistake, you'll still have a command line to repair it.

Tip: you can [create a `toor` account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124968/what-are-the-side-effects-of-having-several-unix-users-share-one-uid/124985#124985) with UID 0 (so it's still root), with the same password as root, and where the shell remains `/bin/sh`, so that you keep another way to log in if things break. Better yet, install a statically linked shell (`busybox-static` or `zsh-static`) and use that as toor's login shell.

¹  <sub>Or you can use [guestfs](http://libguestfs.org/) if the host is Linux.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great trick with changing the init! It helped me in a situation where I had to edit fstab to allow normal booting :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the root password, you can run `su -s /bin/bash` to get a root bash shell.

`sudo -s /bin/bash` should work too, and depending on how `sudo` is configured you'll either need to know only your own password or no password.

You can then use `chsh -s /bin/bash` to change root's shell back to bash.

BTW, it's generally a bad idea to change root's shell on any unix system.  Many cron jobs etc depend on root's shell being the default root shell for that OS and **WILL** break if you change it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution which we have tried is using `init` command.

I have executed the command `init 1` on terminal and then able to login using `root` user.

Once authenticated, edited the `/etc/passwd` file to change the shell from `/bin/zsh` to `/bin/sh`.

Once this is done, able to login using `root` user.

Answer (score -2):

Pls try sudo vi /etc/passwd
And enter your currently  logged user  password.

Also you can find shell correct path in /etc/shell

And to check current shell pls try echo $SHELL

Comment: As I mentioned, I cannot do a sudo or a su, when I do sudo it shows: **sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have setuid bit set** and on su it asks for passwd but when entered correct password it gives ** Cannot execute which zsh: No such file or directory**

Comment: -1, I'm afraid everything you suggest is wrong: 1) The OP can't use `sudo` as explained in their question; 2) You mean `/etc/shells` not `/etc/shell`; 3) `$SHELL` doesn't show the currently running shell, it shows the default for the user. In any case, how is that relevant?

Comment: `/etc/shell` will not give you the required output.