# POSIX compatible way to get user name associated with a user ID

Tags: users, posix

I often want to get the login name associated with a user ID and because it’s proven to be a common use case, I decided to write a shell function to do this.  While I primarily use GNU/Linux distributions, I try to write my scripts to be as portable as possible and to check that what I’m doing is POSIX-compatible.

#### Parse `/etc/passwd`

The first approach I tried was to parse `/etc/passwd` (using `awk`).

```bsh
awk -v uid="$uid" -F: '$3 == uid {print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

However, the problem with this approach is that the logins may not be local, e.g., user authentication could be via NIS or LDAP.

#### Use the `getent` command

Using `getent passwd` is more portable than parsing `/etc/passwd` as this also queries non-local NIS or LDAP databases.

- [getent - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getent)
- [getent(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getent)

```bsh
getent passwd "$uid" | cut -d: -f1
```

Unfortunately, the `getent` utility does not seem to be specified by POSIX.

#### Use the `id` command

[`id`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/id.html) is the POSIX-standardised utility for getting data about a user’s identity.

BSD and GNU implementations accept a User ID as an operand:

- [id(1) - OpenBSD manual pages](https://man.openbsd.org/id.1)
- [id(1) – FreeBSD man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=id&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports)
- [GNU Coreutils: id invocation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/id-invocation.html)

This means it can be used to print the login name associated with a User ID:

```bsh
id -nu "$uid"
```

However, providing User IDs as the operand is not specified in POSIX; it only describes the use of a *login name* as the operand.

#### Combining all of the above

I considered combining the above three approaches into something like the following:

```bsh
get_username(){
    uid="$1"
    # First try using getent
    getent passwd "$uid" | cut -d: -f1 ||
        # Next try using the UID as an operand to id.
        id -nu "$uid" ||
        # As a last resort, parse `/etc/passwd`.
        awk -v uid="$uid" -F: '$3 == uid {print $1}' /etc/passwd
}
```

However, this is clunky, inelegant and – more importantly – not robust; it exits with a non-zero status if the User ID is invalid or does not exist.  Before I write a longer and clunkier shell script that analyses and stores the exit status of each command invocation, I thought I’d ask here:

*Is there a more elegant and portable (POSIX-compatible) way of getting the login name associated with a user ID?*

Comment: For added fun, consider that multiple usernames can map to the same id...

Comment: The issue with multiple usernames mapped to the same id in the context of this question is that neither `getent` nor `id` will return anything past the first match; the only way to find them all is to enumerate all users, if the user database allows that. (Looking in `/etc/passwd` works for users defined there, obviously.)

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt  I created such an entry in my `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` to test this scenario and verified that both `id` and `getent passwd` behave as you describe. If, at some stage, I end up using a system where a user has multiple names, I'll do the same as these system utilities and simply treat the first occurrence as the canonical name for that user.

Comment: That’s probably the only sensible approach... (And in any case, as mentioned by Gilles in his answer to the question you linked above, having multiple usernames for the same id isn’t a good idea. I use it to provide static shells for root, but that’s increasingly irrelevant anyway.)

Comment: @StephenKitt While trying to prevent comment clutter from building up, I deleted the comment which contains the link to Gilles' answer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124968/22812  just before you posted your comment.

Comment: Does POSIX require a user id to be associated with a user name __at all__? Any program running as root can call `setuid(some_id)`, and there's no requirement that `some_id` may be part of any user database. With such things as user namespaces on Linux this may turn to be a crippling assumption for your scripts.

Comment: Maybe a little slow, but this is supposed to work on any system and only relies on a public viewable file of that user: `find / -user 42 2>/dev/null -exec ls -do {} \; |cut -d" " -f 3|head -n 1`

Comment: @Philippos that breaks for user account names containing a space. (Hello Active Directory, I'm looking at you...) On the other hand, POSIX states that conforming usernames must not contain a space, so for POSIX conformance you're fine.

Comment: @Philippos that seems like an expensive way of calling the `getpwuid()` function which `ls` uses to translate UIDs to login names. [Gilles’ answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/541475/22812) is a more direct and efficient way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One common way to do this is to test if the program you want exists and is available from your `PATH`.  For example:

```bsh
get_username(){
  uid="$1"

  # First try using getent
  if command -v getent > /dev/null 2>&1; then 
    getent passwd "$uid" | cut -d: -f1

  # Next try using the UID as an operand to id.
  elif command -v id > /dev/null 2>&1 && \
       id -nu "$uid" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    id -nu "$uid"

  # Next try perl - perl's getpwuid just calls the system's C library getpwuid
  elif command -v perl >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    perl -e '@u=getpwuid($ARGV[0]);
             if ($u[0]) {print $u[0]} else {exit 2}' "$uid"

  # As a last resort, parse `/etc/passwd`.
  else
      awk -v uid="$uid" -F: '
         BEGIN {ec=2};
         $3 == uid {print $1; ec=0; exit 0};
         END {exit ec}' /etc/passwd
  fi
}
```

Because POSIX `id` doesn't support UID arguments, the  `elif` clause for `id` has to test not only whether `id` is in the PATH, but also whether it will run without error.  This means it may run `id` twice, which fortunately will not have a noticeable impact on performance.  It is also possible that both `id` and `awk` will be run, with the same negligible performance hit.

BTW, with this method, there's no need to store the output.  Only one of them will be run, so only one will print output for the function to return.

Comment: to cope with the possibility of multiple usernames having the same uid, wrap everything from `if` to `fi` in `{ ... } | head -n 1`.   i.e. drop all but the first uid match.  but that will mean you'll have to capture the exit code of whatever program got run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping that there might be some other utility that I hadn’t come across but this is helpful. Because I don’t have access to an implementation of `id` that doesn’t accept an ID as an operand, I figured testing its exit status could be problematic – how to tell the difference between a login name that doesn’t exist or a UID that doesn’t exist. It’s possible for a login name to consist of only numerical characters: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Disambiguating-names-and-IDs.html#Disambiguating-names-and-IDs

Comment: i didn't consider that.....but a) that case will fall through to `awk` anyway, and b) the awk code there will always have an exit code of 0 whether the uid was matched or not.

Comment: fixed the awk script so that it exits with 2 if not found, same as getent.

Comment: btw, the awk command will fail if the user data is stored in nis or ldap or active directory or something other than /etc/passwd.  obvious, but worth mentioning.  it's probably the only reason why it's worthwhile running `id`.

Comment: With every edit, the function is becoming more robust. :) On that note, I’d probably use `if command -v getent >/dev/null;` instead of `if [ -x /usr/bin/getent ] ;` on the off-chance that these utilities have a different path.

Comment: is `command -v` posix?  i started with `type -p` and then realised that `-p` isn't posix.

Comment: Yes. I regularly use `command -v` for this purpose: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html (though I've only ever tested it with the `dash` shell builtin).

Comment: neither getent, id, nor the awk script will ever return more than one username....so the `{...} | head -n1` and $rc is no longer needed.  i'll delete all that.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan If you ever have to work on ancient systems, `type foo >/dev/null 2>/dev/null` works on every sh that I've ever seen. `command` is comparatively modern.

Comment: BTW `$uid` really should be a local variable.  but that's difficult to do in a portable, posix-compliant way.   See [List of shells that support `local` keyword for defining local variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493729/list-of-shells-that-support-local-keyword-for-defining-local-variables)

Comment: Also, the perl variation I added doesn't output a LF after the username.  That shouldn't matter, but if your calling code relies on it for some reason, change the print to `print $u[0], "\n"`

Answer (score 8):

POSIX specifies [`getpwuid`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwuid.html) as a standard C function to search the user database for a user ID allowing the ID to be translated to a login name. I downloaded the source code for GNU *coreutils* and can see this function being used in their implementation of utilities such as `id` and `ls`.

As a learning exercise, I wrote this quick-and-dirty C program to simply act as a wrapper for this function. Bear in mind that I haven’t programmed in C since college (many years ago) and I don’t intend to use this in production but I thought I’d post it here as a proof of concept (if anyone wants to edit it, feel free):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  /* atoi */
#include <pwd.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    uid_t uid;
    if ( argc >= 2 ) {
        /* NB: atoi returns 0 (super-user ID) if argument is not a number) */
        uid = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    /* Ignore any other arguments after the first one. */
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "One numeric argument must be supplied.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct passwd *pwd;
    pwd = getpwuid(uid);
    if (pwd) {
        printf("The login name for %d is: %s\n", uid, pwd->pw_name);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid user ID: %d\n", uid);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I didn’t have the chance to test it with NIS/LDAP but I noticed that if there are multiple entries for the same user in `/etc/passwd`, it ignores all but the first.

Example usage:

```
$ ./get_user ""
The login name for 0 is: root

$ ./get_user 99
Invalid user ID: 99
```

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing in POSIX that would help other than `id`. Trying `id` and falling back to parsing `/etc/passwd` is probably as portable as it gets in practice.

BusyBox's `id` doesn't accept user IDs, but systems with BusyBox are usually autonomous embedded systems where parsing `/etc/passwd` is enough.

In case you encounter a non-GNU system where `id` doesn't accept user IDs, you could also try calling [`getpwuid`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwuid.html) via Perl, on the chance that it's available:

```
username=$(perl -e 'print((getpwuid($ARGV[0]))[0])) 2>/dev/null
if [ -n "$username" ]; then echo "$username"; return; fi
```

Or Python:

```
if python -c 'import pwd, sys; print(pwd.getpwuid(int(sys.argv[1]))).pw_name' 2>/dev/null; then return; fi
```

Comment: Parsing `/etc/passwd` is not portable at all, and will not work for non-passwd-file backends like LDAP.

Comment: I like that, I'll steal it

Comment: @R.. The asker is aware of that, this answer doesn't claim otherwise, so what's the point of your comment?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm reassured that there isn't some other utility that I wasn't aware of. It looks like POSIX specifies a standard C function to translate UID to a login name but not necessarily a corresponding command (other than `id`).

Comment: As a last fallback, check if there is a c compiler on the system, then compile a supplied getpwuid() wrapper ...

Comment: POSIX XCU specifies a `c99` command. :-)

Comment: @Gilles: I was speaking to "probably as portable as it gets in practice". For example it wouldn't work on most Alpine Linux systems (BusyBox `id` by default) with non-passwd-file-backend user db.

Comment: cc is POSIX as is getpwuid; build a program and execute it.

Comment: @Joshua Not quite: it's part of the “C-Language Development Utilities” extension, which in practice is not present on lots of POSIX-compliant systems, usually because it's part of an optional package which is not installed. Also, `cc` has not been POSIX in a long time, and even when it was there was no guarantee that it would compile anything correctly (it was an unspecified variant of the C language, which could have been K&R C or might not link requisite libraries). POSIX specifies `c99` (and in earlier times `c89`).

Answer (score 3):

Generally, I would recommend against doing this. The mapping from user names to uids is not one-to-one, and encoding assumptions that you can convert *back from* a uid to get a username is going to break things. For example, I often run completely root-free user-namespace containers by making the `passwd` and `group` files in the container map all user and group names to id 0; this allows installing packages to work without `chown` failing. But if something tries to convert 0 back to a uid and doesn't get what it expects, it will gratuitously break. So in this example, instead of converting back and comparing usernames, you should convert to uids and compare in that space.

If you really do need to do this operation, it might be possible to do semi-portably if you're root, by making a temp file, `chown`ing it to the uid, then using `ls` to read back and parse the owner's name. But I would just use a well-known approach that's not standardized but "portable in practice", like one of the ones you found already.

But again, don't do this. Sometimes something being hard to do is sending you a message.

Comment: Comments purged. I'd like to remind _both_ participants that comments need to be civil.